# Angular 4 testing: how to spy on a service inside host component?

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I have a component, which uses service to retreive data. It takes gallery ID as input.

```
export class GalleryComponent implements OnInit {
  private photos: Photo[] = [];
  @Input() private galleryId: number;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.galleryService.getPhotos(this.galleryId)
      .subscribe((photos: Photo[]) => this.photos = photos);
  }
}
```

And I am trying to test it using a host component:

```
describe('Gallery Component', () => {

  const fakePhotos: Photo[] = [
    {id: 1, photo: 'http://example.com/lena.jpg'} as Photo,
    {id: 2, photo: 'http://example.com/mario.jpg'} as Photo,
  ];

  @Component({
    template: `<gallery [galleryId]="1"></gallery>`
  })
  class TestHostComponent {}

  // ...SKIP CONFIGURATION

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestHostComponent);

    const galleryService = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(GalleryService);
    spyOn(galleryService, 'getPhotos').and.returnValue(Observable.of(fakePhotos));

    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

});
```

But `getPhotos` method of the service is never called. So how should I properly spy on `getPhotos` method of a child component?

Answer (score 1):

I actually tried to spy on the wrong instance of a service. Right service should be inside my `GalleryComponent` and not inside `TestHostComponent`.

I ended up with creating `GalleryService` mock class:

```
class MockService extends GalleryService {
    getPhotos(galleryId: number) {
      return Observable.of(fakePhotos);
    }
}
```

and overriding component providers before compiling components:

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.overrideComponent(GalleryComponent, {
      set: {providers: [{provide: GalleryService, useClass: MockService}]}
    });

    // ...SKIP
}));
```

And now I do not need to spy on a service at all.